# Relação entre tabelas de mesmos valores nas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero fazer uma consulta sql que relacione duas colunas de duas tabelas diferentes, que armazenam os mesmos tipos de valores, mas uma possui alguns que a outra não contém, exemplo:

**Tabela 1** possui a **coluna codigo** e

**Tabela 2** possui a **coluna code**

Quero fazer uma consulta que exiba todas as linhas(valores) de **code** que **não estejam** em **codigo**

Desde já, agradeço por qualquer ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução (entre outras) é usar um sub-select com not exists, verifica a existência de valores no sub-select

```
select * 
from tabela2
where not exists (select null
                  from tabela1
                  where tabela1.codigo = tabela2.code)
```

Comment: Não funciona, diz que a coluna codigo não pertence a tabela1 na linha 5, mesmo pertencendo

Comment: De fato. Foi corrigido.